# How to know which features have more impact in predicting the target class?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I have a business problem, I have run the regression model in python to predict my target value. When validating it with my test set I came to know that my predicted variable is very far from my actual value. Now the thing I want to extract from this model is that, which feature played the role to deviate my predicted value from actual value (let say difference is in some threshold value)? 
I want to rank the features impact wise so that I could address to my client.
Thanks

Comment: what is the regression model, which you are using?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the estimator you chose, linear models often have a coef_ method you can call to get the coef used for each feature, given they are normalized this tells you what you want to know.

As told above for tree model you have the feature importance. You can also use libraries like treeinterpreter described here:
[Interpreting Random Forest](http://blog.datadive.net/interpreting-random-forests/)

[examples](http://blog.datadive.net/random-forest-interpretation-with-scikit-learn/)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this -
[Feature selection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check the Random [Forest Regressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) - for performing Regression.

```py
# Example 
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
X, y = make_regression(n_features=4, n_informative=2,
                       random_state=0, shuffle=False)
regr = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=2, random_state=0,
                             n_estimators=100)
regr.fit(X, y)
print(regr.feature_importances_)
print(regr.predict([[0, 0, 0, 0]]))
```

Check `regr.feature_importances_` for getting the higher, more important features. Further information on [FeatureImportance](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.feature_importances_)

**Edit-1:**
As pointed out in user (@blacksite) comment, only `feature_importance` does not provide complete interpretation of Random forest. For further analysis of results and responsible Features. Please refer to following blogs

- https://medium.com/usf-msds/intuitive-interpretation-of-random-forest-2238687cae45  (**preferred** as it provides multiple techniques )
- https://blog.datadive.net/interpreting-random-forests/ (**focuses** on 1 technique but also provides python library - [treeinterpreter](https://github.com/andosa/treeinterpreter))

**More on feature_importance:**

- If you simply use the feature_importances_ attribute to select the
  features with the highest importance score.  [Feature selection using
  feature
  importances](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/6683/9638)
- Feature importance also depends on the criteria used for splitting
  and calculating importance [Interpreting Decision Tree in context of
  feature
  importances](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/37571/9638)

Comment: This doesn't explicitly tell you what is important for predicting either class -- feature importances basically indicate each feature's importance in terms of discriminating between the two classes, not predicting a particular class.

Comment: So what technique could be used to know the cause of prediction? Let say in prediction my target value is price, once price is predicted by the model, it could either be high or low. I want to know the cause of price to be low or High, in short which features play their role in predicting the price as low or high.

Comment: You could start with feature_importance - which will tell you that price was low because of these features and price was high because of some other features. You could go deeper using [treeinterpreter](https://github.com/andosa/treeinterpreter) to get exact interpretation of how the regression was done using Decsion trees/Forests. Ideally you need to be a domain expert  to do causal analysis of the results obtained.